# Сложная выборка с учётом рейтинга

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
Есть таблица с коментариями, у каждого коментария есть оценка.

Нужно вывести коментарии по принципу: 3 комента с оценкой 4,5 затем один камент с оценкой 3 и ниже затем снова по тому же принципу

Примерно как на картинке
[image]

Comment: ничего не понял -)

Comment: В общем чтоб список коментарив выводился так
3 хороших 1 плохой
3 хороших 1 плохой
и т.д. )))

Хорошие-плохие определяются по оценке

Comment: и все это средствами sql?

Comment: Если можно. С php у меня есть реализация.

Comment: Что делать, если закончились 4,5 или 1–3?

Comment: выдавать то что соталось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно так:

```
select c_id, c_mark
from (
  select c_id, c_mark, 
    if(@r1%4=3,@r1:=@r1+2,@r1:=@r1+1) as cusom_order
  from comments, (select @r1 := 0) o1
  where c_mark>3
  union all
  select c_id, c_mark, 
    @r2:=@r2+4
  from comments, (select @r2 := 0) o2
  where c_mark<=3
) custom_ordered_commencts
order by cusom_order;
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает